# tf.diag of a 2D matrix

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, diagonal

I have a 2D tensor with various arrays defined as:

```
x = tf.constant([[0,1,2],[-1,0,1],[-1,-2,0]])
```

and I want to convert each array to a diagonal matrix as:

```
diag_x =
[[[ 0,  0,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  0,  2]],
 [[-1,  0,  0],
  [ 0,  0,  0],
  [ 0,  0,  1]],
 [[-2,  0,  0],
  [ 0, -1,  0],
  [ 0,  0,  0]]]
```

but if I use the operation *tf.diag(x)* the output is not this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
tf.matrix_diag(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: For TF 2.0, you can use

```
tf.linalg.diag(x)
```

You can try:

```
tf.matrix_set_diag(tf.zeros((3,3,3), dtype=tf.int32), x)
```

Comment: It is a good solution! However, I forgot to mention that in my case I have *x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 3])* with undefined number of samples. I mean, Is there a way to do *tf.matrix_set_diag(tf.zeros((None,3,3), dtype=tf.int32), x)*?

Comment: I'd go with `matrix_diag` as per your answer, but just for completeness: yes! Using `tf.shape` to get an integer Tensor for the batch size, then passing that instead of `None` to `tf.zeros`.